Check when vectors are uploaded to Pinecone namespace
I have a pinecone index set up and I am using Langchain to upload my prepared Documents to a certain namespace.
My problem is that, I am returning the PineconeVectorStore and passing that as a parameter to another class; however, Pinecone takes a few seconds to completely be done with all the vector uploading.
Is there anyway to check if it is completely done beside using time.sleep() because I don't find it as an elegant solution and there is no guarantee that all the vectors have uploaded at this point.
I am using the below code to insert my data to Pinecone Index.
from typing import List
from langchain_core.documents import Document
from langchain_openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain_pinecone import PineconeVectorStore


embed_model = OpenAIEmbeddings(
    model='text-embedding-3-small'
)

def upload_data(docs: List(Document), embed_model, index_name: str, namespace:str) -> PineconeVectorStore:
    vector_store = PineconeVectorStore.from_documents(
        documents=docs,
        embedding=embed_model,
        index_name=index_name,
        namespace=namespace
    )
    time.sleep(4) # change this part
    # I have created my index outside of this snippet of code
    # when I do my_index.describe_index_states() before and after the time.sleep I get different number of total_vector_count
    return vector_store


Langchain does not natively support tracking the progress of from_documents at the moment. Consider passing each Document separately inside a for looping and tracking its progress. Example

Maybe look at this https://docs.pinecone.io/guides/data/data-freshness/understanding-data-freshness :)
You can use the LSN in requests headers to know if the operation is complete or not.
